# Jquery trigger not triggering element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to get a trigger working but this doesn't seem to work. Im 100% sure this is the right code to do the job.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".relrightbutton" ).click(function() {
    $( ".attachment-large" ).trigger( "click" );
  });
});
```

however is there another way to trigger an element click when a different element is clicked?

Comment: what kind of handler is attached to `attachment-large` or what is expected when the event is triggered

Comment: Try `$( ".attachment-large" )[0].click()`

Comment: Can you add `html` structure

Comment: So basically i have a custom built lightbox, with a thumbnail carousel of related images bellow. Either side are two arrows and when clicking these arrows i need them to "auto" click the next thumbnail as that is the only way i can have this function to work.

Comment: your code is looking perfect till now, so post the html may b problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you adding dynamic elements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see flaws in that code. It might be something else then (classnames are correct?)

You could try getting the click on another thread:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".relrightbutton" ).click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( ".attachment-large" ).trigger( "click" );
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

Or try another click method trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".relrightbutton" ).click(function() {
        $( ".attachment-large" ).click();
    });
});
```

Is there no error message provided in your console?

Comment: No error messages, and still nothings working. Is there not way to do this in plain javascript?